# IIS7 app pools shutting down while hosting WCF services with net.tcp

Tags: wcf, iis-7, application-pool, net.tcp

I'm hosting WCF services in IIS 7/WAS on Windows Server 2008 using http and net.tcp bindings.

I'm able to call the services with both http and net.tcp without issue most of the time, but occasionally the services' app pool will shut down unexpectedly.  When this happens, WAS writes the following entries to the event log:

> The worker process for application pool 'MyServices' encountered an error '' trying to read configuration data from file '\?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\web.config', line number '0'. The data field contains the error code. (Data: 00000008)
>
> A process serving application pool 'MyServices' reported a failure trying to read configuration during startup. The process id was '18196'. Please check the Application Event Log for further event messages logged by the worker process on the specific error. The data field contains the error number. (Data: 80004005)
>
> A listener channel for protocol 'net.tcp' in worker process '18468' serving application pool 'MyServices' reported a listener channel failure. The data field contains the error number. (Data: 80004005)
>
> Application pool 'MyServices' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

I've confirmed the app pool is configured to use .NET v4.0, integrated mode, with 32-bit applications disabled.  The services don't use any 32-bit or unmanaged components.

The calls leading up to the shutdown are net.tcp calls, one app log entry mentions a "listener channel for protocol 'net.tcp'", and net.tcp is much less common than http (I haven't found anything relevant Googling any of the app log entries).  I can't help but think the problem is related to net.tcp, port sharing, etc.  I just have no idea what the problem might be.

Has anyone encountered this before?  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to troubleshoot the problem, beyond simply disabling net.tcp and using http exclusively?